# UIImageView won't retain a square shape.

Tags: ios

I'm not sure what the problem is, I mean it was working fine one day, and then I woke up and it was broken. Here's what I'm dealing with.

I have a View that is `height: 80, width: 80` and an image that is `height: 76, width: 76` This image is a child-view to the view that is 80x80. I am centering the image with a 2px border around the view, to give the image a "Border" feel.  (Yes, I know I can probably do this in code by editing the Image layer).

Anyway, In the interface builder, and preview pane everything looks exactly as it should. However on the device that's another story, below are my constraints for my image:

[image]

I've also tried using an aspect-ratio 1:1 constraint, the image type is set to "Aspect Fill". The issue is that the image does not retain the square shape (76x76) and goes completely out of its bounds:

[image]

If you look above and below the picture, you can see the small border of the parent 80x80 view there. The image on the otherhand, is just not listening to constaints.

Comment: Indeed, to add a border, just set `layer.borderWidth` and `layer.borderColor` instead of adding another view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that while the image *view* is indeed square, the *image* is not. Thus you have two alternatives:

- To keep the whole image inside the image view's bounds, change the image view's content mode to Aspect *Fit* (instead of Aspect Fill).
- Alternatively, set the image view's "clips to bounds" to true. But note that this will mean that the edges of your nonrectangular image will be lost.

Comment: This does not retain the shape, and instead shrinks down the rectangular image, the issue (which I had just found) was that the "Clip Subviews" option was not checked.

Your comment is correct, however- cutting off some of the image to keep aspect is the goal.

Comment: Right, I was going to add that as well. Note that that means, however, that you'll lose the edges of the picture.

Comment: I'm aware, thanks for the information though. Edit that in and I'll accept the answer when the timer is done.

Comment: Yup, no problem. It's unclear what result you want, so you are right to get me to fill in both alternative approaches, each of which has its advantages and disadvantages.