# Background image hides all other UI element like label in iOS app(written in swift4) when traversing back in page view controller

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

Background image hides all other UI elements when traversing back pages of Page view controller.
What can be the possible reason? **This only happens when pages are swiped backward** and an **background image is set** and content mode is set **to scaleAspectFill**, forward swiping of page works fine.
If I change (backgroundImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit) it works ok.
I set the background image of View Controller in View Did Load.

Below is the code of View Controller that is instantiated for pageviewcontroller.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var dayDescription: UILabel!

    var descriptionPassed: descriptionPassed? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
    setBackGround()
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)

            if let descInDetail = descriptionPassed {

                self.dayDescription.text = descInDetail.dataDetail[0].w_description
    }

     func setBackGround(){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print("In dispatch main)

                        let backgroundImage = UIImage.init(named: imageToPutInBackground)
                        let backgroundImageView = UIImageView.init(frame: self.view.frame)

                        backgroundImageView.image = backgroundImage
                        backgroundImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                        backgroundImageView.alpha = 0.9

                        self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImageView, at: 0)
                    }
    }
}
```

Page View Controller Code

```
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController,UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate{

    var desc = [Desc]()
    var passSignalToHideButtonInContentVC : Bool = false
    var pageControl = UIPageControl()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self

        //self.configurePageControl()

        let initialContenViewController = self.pageAtIndex(0) as ViewController
        self.setViewControllers([initialContenViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.red
        self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black  

    }

    func pageAtIndex(_ index: Int) ->ViewController
    {

        let pageContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageContent") as! ViewController

        if desc.count == 0 {

            pageContentViewController.pageIndex = 0

            return pageContentViewController

        }else {

            let desc = self.desc[index]
            pageContentViewController.desc = desc
            pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index
            pageContentViewController.hideFavButton = passSignalToHideButtonInContentVC

            return pageContentViewController

        }
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        let viewController = viewController as! ViewController
        var index = viewController.pageIndex as Int
        pageControl.currentPage = index 
        if(index == 0 || index == NSNotFound)
        {
            return nil
        }

        index -= 1

        return self.pageAtIndex(index)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        let viewController = viewController as! ViewController
        var index = viewController.pageIndex as Int
        pageControl.currentPage = index //move dot
        if((index == NSNotFound))
        {
            return nil
        }

        index += 1

        if(index == desc.count)
        {
            return nil
        }

        return self.pageAtIndex(index)
    }

    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return desc.count
    }

    func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    } 

}
```

Comment: I do not understand why this question is marked off-topic. I removed the swift4 tag and now it is seems quite legit to ask it here. All those who have marked this off-topic, kindly let me know. I really need an answer to my posted question so if it needs another tag or whatever let me know. I am not well aware of stack overflow stringent rules. Thanks

Comment: ok, I will do so soon. But I didn't do so because I really do not understand which part of my lengthy code is really creating an issue. That is why I gave the code where in I set the background. Thanks!

Comment: I tried running the code with setBackGround() in viewDidAppear, didn't solve the issue and caused delay in loading image.

Comment: Nice experiment. "So you claim that the image view appears in front of the other views even though you are inserting it at index 0?" Yes, that is my query.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this by setting clipsToBound property to true.

```
backgroundImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Yes, a common problem, see for example my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34833579/341994